# Внутренние отступы в окне Java FX

Tags: java, windows, javafx

Создал окно. Добавил элементов. Когда запускаю у меня справа и снизу есть отступ внутренний, пикселей 5-6. Если я сделать UNDECORATED то эти отступы пропадут. Подскажите пожалуйста как это пофиксить? UNDECORATED не нужен.

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane id="pane" fx:id="authPane" maxHeight="530.0" maxWidth="794.0" minHeight="530.0" minWidth="794.0" prefHeight="530.0" prefWidth="794.0" stylesheets="@../css/auth.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.flauncher.admin.controller.Panel">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="794.0">
         <children>
            <Button id="cheatsPane" fx:id="openCheats" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="264.0" text="Читы" />
            <Button fx:id="openTextures" layoutX="265.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="264.0" text="Текстуры" />
            <Button layoutX="530.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="264.0" text="Сервера" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="794.0">
         <children>
            <Pane id="cheats" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="794.0" visible="false" />
            <Pane id="textures" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="794.0">
               <children>
                  <ListView fx:id="texturesList" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="264.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="263.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="531.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20;" text="Добавить текстуру" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="59.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TabPane layoutX="263.0" layoutY="339.0" prefHeight="85.0" prefWidth="531.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFF;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                     <tabs>
                        <Tab text="1.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="oneUrl" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="oneUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.2.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="twoUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="twoUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.3.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="threeUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="threeUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.4.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="fourUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="fourUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.5.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="fiveUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="fiveUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.6.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="sixUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="sixUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.7.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="sevenUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="sevenUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.8.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="eightUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="eightUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.9.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="nineUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="nineUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.10.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="tenUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" text="https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/faithful-32x/files/2323077/download" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="tenUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.11.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="elevenUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" text="https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/faithful-32x/files/2323077/download" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="elevenUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="1.12.*">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="twelveUrl" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="306.0" text="https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/faithful-32x/files/2480942/download" />
                                    <CheckBox fx:id="twelveUse" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Использовать">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Ссылка на файл" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                     </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
                  <Label layoutX="281.0" layoutY="247.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="254.0" style="-fx-font-size: 10;" text="* Будет использоваться как главная" textFill="RED" />
                  <Label layoutX="282.0" layoutY="312.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Картинка 3">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="image3" layoutX="401.0" layoutY="308.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="383.0" text="https://media-elerium.cursecdn.com/attachments/37/336/2016-06-13_04.png" />
                  <Label layoutX="282.0" layoutY="281.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Картинка 2">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="image2" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="277.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="383.0" text="https://media-elerium.cursecdn.com/attachments/37/337/2016-06-13_03.png" />
                  <TextField fx:id="image1" layoutX="401.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="383.0" text="https://media-elerium.cursecdn.com/attachments/114/81/2016-11-14_14.png" />
                  <Label layoutX="282.0" layoutY="226.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Картинка 1">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="283.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Описание">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Button layoutX="385.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMousePressed="#onSave" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="Добавить" />
                  <Label layoutX="282.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Название">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="401.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="383.0" text="Faithful [32x]" />
                  <TextArea fx:id="description" layoutX="401.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="383.0" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane id="servers" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="794.0" visible="false" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Auth.css

```
@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/font/10318.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/font/big_noodle_titling.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/font/3962.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/font/2211.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/font/10089.ttf");
}

.button {
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}

#pane {
    -fx-font-family: "BigNoodleTooOblique";
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    -fx-background-image: url("../assets/background.jpg");
}

#title {
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
}

#tab-cheats,
#tab-textures {
    -fx-pref-width: 384;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете общий класс Pane в качестве корневого контейнера. Он содержит меньше настраиваемых параметров, нежели наследующие его классы. Возможно, следует использовать AnchorPane и следующие настройки

[image: Отступы]

[image: Занимать все свободное пространство]